# How to dynamically create navigation bar based on the role of user in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

have googled search for a while but still couldn't get the right articles or examples to put me through. I'm currently working(learning) on a role based application which i doing well. I'm currently having a problem. i have a table in my sql db called SiteMap. This table has the following columns (id, Title, Description, Url, roles, parentId, TabType and TabOrder). I have values for each columns. What i want to achieve is that when a user logs in, i want to have navbar based on the role of that user. If the user is a guest, I want to display a navbar with the roles of just guest. How do i have this?

here is how the db looks like

id Title      Description       Url      roles   parentId   TabType   TabOrder

1   ROOT         ROOT                      *       NULL       0         0

2 Administrator Padmin     PortalAdmin#   Admin      1        1         2

3 Report                    Reporting#    Admin      1        1         3

4 Ticket                    Ticket#     Admin;Guest  1        1         4

5 ManageTicket            Mticket.aspx     Guest     4        4         2

here is a summary of what i want to do. When a user that is with the role of guest logs in, only Ticket(with sub menu Manage Ticket) should be in the navbar. If its a user with Admin role, Portal Administration, Report, Ticket(with submenu Manage Ticket) should be displayed in the navbar. I hope you do understand what i explained. Thanks

Comment: Need to provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

Make a dedicated action for the Navbar on the HomeController. The action should determine the type of user, and translate this into a view model. Something like this (with accompanying view model class)

```
    public ActionResult Navbar()
    {
        var model = new NavbarViewModel()
        {
            Administrator = User.IsInRole("Admin"),
            Reporting = User.IsInRole("Reporting")
        };
        return PartialView(model);
    }

    public class NavbarViewModel
    {
        public bool Administrator { get; set; }
        public bool Reporting { get; set; }
    }
```

Copy the navbar root div in the _Layout.cshtml into the Navbar view and replace it in _Layout.cshtml with :

```
           @{Html.RenderAction("Navbar","Home");}
```

Use standard Razor to render the navbar elements.

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            @if (Model.Administrator)
            {
                <li>ADMINISTRATOR LINK</li>
            }
            @if (Model.Reporting)
            {
                <li>REPORTING LINK</li>
            }
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question directly but I hope this points you in the right direction. Assuming you have or are going to create a Users table with a column that can house the users roles (permission levels essentially), I would have you a query to check the roles of the individual user on log in and display the navbar associated with that role. Meaning on during the log in verification process when you are checking to see if the user exists and has the right credentials I would retrieve its "role" or permission level and store it in the session data. Then use that stored item to query the "SiteMap" table for the navbar where users "permission" or "role" is like the navbar role. Once that is retrieved all you need to do is display it on the page.

If it is a guest that is accessing the page you can have the Guest navbar as default that will change only after a user actually logs in.

You can do a little research into User permissions and storing session data on login.

I really hope this helps. I can't do much more without looking at your code to see whats going on.